# Asp.Net Core which uses app.useSpa() and handles 404s

Tags: c#, .net, angular, asp.net-core, middleware

We have an Asp.Net Core application that wraps a Spa (Angular) using the :

```
app.useSpa()
```

middleware. Works great.

When a page request comes in that is a non-existent url (often a request for a page from the previous technology stack .aspx) we handle it in Angular's router.

However the app.useSpa() middleware throws an error in .net that is caught and published.

How do we get asp.useSpa() to not throw an error (below) when a 404 '.aspx' page is requested?

The exception is:

**System.InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.**

Comment: Is there any tutorial you followed can be shared here sir? That may help us to reproduce your issue, I can't catch your situation well.

Answer (score 0):

From the Microsoft documentation, they say:

> Handles all requests from this point in the middleware chain by returning the default page for the Single Page Application (SPA).

This means any request to a route that hasn't yet found a controller will always return the default SPA page, and not throw a 404. That exception that you have there is something else and has nothing to do with the problem raised about "useSpa()". It is a configuration problem or something else... A common issue is the  trailing slash in the API Url of the Angular application for example.